# Relative minimal surface and minimal surface in the algebraic geometry

Tags: algebraic-geometry, minimal-surfaces, birational-geometry

Liu's book define regular fibered surface X$\to$S is relative minimal surface if it does not contain any exceptional divisor,  regular fibered surface X $\to$ S is minimal surface if every birational map of regular fibered S-surfaces Y $\to$ X is a birational morphism. It is hard for me to understand them, here are my questions:

> 1. Given a regular fibered surface, how to judge whether it is relative minimal or  minimal?
> 2. Does any typical examples to show what they look like?
> 3. Why we call it minimal here ? Does any relation with the minimal surface in the differential geometry?

Comment: Generally, what you quote as "relative minimal", is defined as: No exceptional divisors, i.e. no -1 curve, in any fibre. The adding "relative" refers to the fibres. The absolute concept is named "minimal", and is defined as "no exceptional divisors in X". What does Liu actually state?

Comment: Liu's definiton is in my question and also an iff condition: every birational morphism of regular fibered surfaces X→Y is isomorphism. I guess  "minimal" means need no blowing-up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X$ be a smooth compact complex surface.

ad 1: To check whether X has no exceptional divisors one can often apply the adjunction formula. Examples:  a) A K3-surface $X$ has trivial canonical divisor, the adjunction formula gives $2g(C) - 2 = C^2$ for any curve $C$ on $X$, hence no -1 curves exist. b) $X = \mathbb P^2$. Each curve $C$ on $\mathbb P^2 $ has positive self intersection number; hence one does not even need the adjunction formula to exclude exceptional divisors.

To determine whether an exceptional divisor $C$ of a surface $X$ is contained in a fibre $F$ of a regular fibration $X \longrightarrow S$ one checks whether $(C,F) = 0$ for the intersection number.

ad 2: A typical example of a surface $X$ with an exceptional divisor is the blow-up of $\mathbb P^2$ in one point; one gets the first Hirzebruch surface $X = \Sigma _1$. Examples of regular fibrations $X \longrightarrow S$ with fibres having exceptional curves are fibrations, which result from a pencil on $X$ with base points and the corresponding rational map $X \longrightarrow \mathbb P^1$, which is undefined at the base points. Blowing up the base points may produce a fibration with exceptional fibres. For an example see [About fibers of an elliptic fibration.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/398349/about-fibers-of-an-elliptic-fibration/1086643#1086643)

ad 3: *Minimal* in complex analysis and algebraic geometry refers to blowing-up and its inverse blowing-down. These methods are very important because they conserve smoothness. Blowing-down is considered a kind of simplifying, e.g., it reduces the Picard group. A surface is minimal when no further blowing-down is possible. Every birational map between surfaces $f:X \longrightarrow Y $ factors as a finite sequence of blow-downs. If $X$ has no exceptional divisors then $f$ is already a morphism.

I do not know any relation to the concept of minimality in differential geometry.

For the domain of algebraic geometry the concept is introduced and explained in the textbook "*Hartshorne, R.*: Algebraic geometry." See also the keywords "monoidal transformation" and "$\sigma$-process" in his book.

Comment: OK,I will read Hartshorne's Algebraic geometry Ch5, now I also want to know what is the difference between the relative minimal surface and minimal surface, does any relative minimal surface which is not minimal?

Comment: Using the definitions from my previous comment: Apparently, any regular fibration of a minimal surface is relatively minimal. The opposite implication does not hold. As an example consider the ruling of the first Hirzebruch surface. You find a definition of "relatively minimal" in the book "Barth, W.; Hulek, K.; Peters, Ch.; van de Ven, A.: Compact Complex Surfaces". The book is a classic for compact surfaces.

Comment: It is a very good book, thanks.